# why std::make_pair is getting input by value instead of by const reference?

Tags: c++

Referring to this web site http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/utility/make_pair/

The std::make_pair has this signature (and possible implementation):

```
template <class T1,class T2>
pair<T1,T2> make_pair (T1 x, T2 y)
{
    return ( pair<T1,T2>(x,y) );
}
```

I am wondering why std::make_pair has input parameter by value and not by const references?

Is there any particular reason for this?

Comment: Interestingly http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/pair.html make_pair takes it arguments by value, but the standard defines them as pass by value

Comment: It's [all better in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/make_pair). All your worries are transient and soon irrelevant.

Comment: from the same page "pair objects can be copy-constructed from other pair objects containing different types, if the respective types are implicitly convertible."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It originally *was* taking the parameters by const reference, but that introduced some unexpected problems. It was changed to pass by value after a defect report:

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#181

It is expected that the compiler will inline the function and be able to optimize away the parameter passing most of the time.

Answer (score 3):

So that `std::make_pair( "abc", 3 )` would work.  If `std::make_pair` took a reference, the deduced type for `T1` would be `char const[4]`, which would generate all sorts of strange error messages because it isn't copyable.